# systemd automount files system as read write, not working as expected (read only)

Tags: systemd, automounting, ntfs

My problem is systemd automount is mounting my ntfs filesystem as read only dispite me setting the `options=rw`

Following some online reference sites on setting up systemd with automount I created two files in attempt to have `/dev/sdb4` mounted to `/mnt/winblows`

I've identified the PARTUUID of the partition, created the directory `/mnt/winblows` owned by `wurst:wurst` (that's my user account), created two files: `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-winblows.automount` and a coresponding `mnt-winblows.mount` With the following contents

mnt-winblows.automount:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automount Winblows

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/winblows

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

mnt-winblows.mount:

```
[Unit]
Description=Winblows

[Mount]
What=PARTUUID=38a287b1-46ca-4cbf-b887-956804a31b2d
Where=/mnt/winblows
Type=ntfs
Options=user,rw,uid=1000,gid=1001

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then performed the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mnt-winblows.automount
```

However, when I touch `/mnt/winblows/test` I get `touch: cannot touch '/mnt/winblows/test': Read-only file system`

I am unsure how to correct this problem as according to man 8 mount the options rw should take care of that.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you change the write permission of `'/mnt/winblows/test'` to writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native **ntfs** Linux kernel driver only provides **read-only** access to a NTFS partition.

In order to get **read/write** access, you should use **ntfs-3g** which is a **FUSE** (filesystem in userspace) driver that provides full **read/write** access. The details might be a bit specific to your Linux distribution.

Look for **ntfs-3g** package and take a look at [man ntfs-3g](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g).